# ALTER USER (Transact-SQL) for Azure SQL DB

Tags: sql-server, azure, alter, azure-sql-database

Can anyone explain to me how to use the following Syntax:

```
-- Syntax for Azure SQL Database     

ALTER USER userName    
     WITH <set_item> [ ,...n ]  

<set_item> ::=   
      NAME = newUserName   
    | DEFAULT_SCHEMA = schemaName  
    | LOGIN = loginName  
    | ALLOW_ENCRYPTED_VALUE_MODIFICATIONS = [ ON | OFF ]   
[;]  

-- Azure SQL Database Update Syntax  
ALTER USER userName    
     WITH <set_item> [ ,...n ]  
[;]  

<set_item> ::=   
      NAME = newUserName   
    | DEFAULT_SCHEMA = { schemaName | NULL }  
    | LOGIN = loginName  
    | PASSWORD = 'password' [ OLD_PASSWORD = 'oldpassword' ]  
    | ALLOW_ENCRYPTED_VALUE_MODIFICATIONS = [ ON | OFF ]   

-- SQL Database syntax when connected to a federation member  
ALTER USER userName  
     WITH <set_item> [ ,… n ]   
[;]
```

I got it from this link https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-user-transact-sql

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The most important use I have found for the ALTER USER is that it helps you map a database user to a server login. It allows to resolve mapping issues between database users and server logins

```
ALTER USER DBuser TO UserLogin
```

You can also use it to change the default schema of a database user

```
ALTER USER [DBUser] WITH DEFAULT_SCHEMA = [NewSch]
```

Finally, you can use it to change password of a SQL Azure contained database user. Contained users do not have a related server login.

```
ALTER USER DBUser WITH PASSWORD = '{your new password}'
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks Alberto, do you know what <set_item> should be replaced with?

Comment: It could be an schema name, a new database user name, a login or a password.

Comment: If this is really for SQL Azure, there is no longer any concept of mapping logins to users because all users are portable database contained users

Comment: @Nick.McDermaid You can have SQL Database contained database user , Azure Active Directory authentication contained database user and SQL users created in master that can be mapped at the database level. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-manage-logins#additional-server-level-administrative-roles